# Background Tasks in Sailsjs

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I need to exec function in Sails controller every minute for example..

I find module called sails-hook-jobs, but it workes only with mongodb...
Modules like "Kue" didn`t work to..

```
getInfo: function (req, res){
        setInterval(function(){
            Ethereum.getInfo("" ,function(err,item){
                sails.log(item);
            });
        })

    }
```

};

Something like this lookes just awfull..

Is there any fine solve to proceed background tasks on sailsjs?

Comment: Kue is a very convenient way to run background jobs. There is a way to bootstrap sails and then run kue workers.

Comment: I'm using sails-hook-node-cron , works fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just stoped with solution calld sails-hook-sheduled
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-hook-schedule

It`s enought for me.